# How do i get a dotted graph material?

Tags: materials, node-editor

example in the photo. want nodes for this, thank you. i can’t find anything on it
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to procedurally generate a texture like that:

[image]

You can change the size and offset of the grid by adjusting the values of the Mapping node, and you can change the size of the dots by adjusting the stops on the ColorRamp node.

Comment: heyyy thanks so much! where are the modulo and distance nodes? i can’t find them. i’m a noob so i know they are under something but idk what they are under lol

Comment: @jasmine They are actually *Vector Math* nodes, you just change the operation in the dropdown box.

Comment: YOURE A LIFE SAVER

Comment: @jasmine Hi. Don't just reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). Same applies for all your previous questions

Comment: ok i’m new here so i forget man, sorry. why can’t i accept text answers as the answer to my question too? i notice it’s only checkmark buttons for photo answers. and the reason i keep forgetting is because a few hours ago i wasn’t even allowed to vote for some reason, had to do with not enough reputation points i think.